# Excel vba step through array with button forward and backward

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a array (red,blue,brown,black) trying to add 6 buttons "right +3" and "left +3" to userform that displays the array element 4 positions 1 to 4. Example if element 3 is displayed "brown", then I click on "left+3", the textbox will now display element 4 "Black" moves 3 positions left 3,2,1,4. Now if i click on "right+3" now it will display "brown" so that it moves 3 positions to the right which would be 4, 1, 2, 3.
 I can subtract or add from array position but if im at position 4 and I add 3 i get error because there is no element 7:

```
MsgBox RARRY(4) + 3
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can check the size of an array with `Ubound(Arrayname)`.

Answer (score 0):

You've not actually actually using an array that is base 1 are you?  That would be the first mistake.

If you have 4 values, then

```
Count = 4
Redim Colours(Count-1)
```

The array should start at 0, so valid indexes should be 0,1,2,3.

Anyway, what you are looking for is the `Mod` function.  It basically gives you the remainder after a division operation.  It's very hand in shifting array indexes in the way that you want.

```
Index = (Index + Offset + Count) Mod Count
```

Using the `Mod` function will guarantee a value between `-Count+1` to `Count-1`

Where `Offset` is any value from `-Count` to `Count`.

The `+ Count` makes sure that you don't actually get any negative values.

If you insist on using an array that starts at base 1 then the formula turns into

```
Index = ((Index - 1 + Offset + Count) Mod Count) + 1
```

Comment: Division by zero error userform1.textbox1 = ((rarray(curretpostion)-1 +3 + count) mod count)+1

Comment: Division by zero error userform1.textbox1 = ((rarray(currentposition)-1 +3 + count) mod count)+1                                                                                     count = 4    currentposition =1 showing red if click on 3 right should display black if I click on 3 left should display blue

Comment: The only way that you would get a *Division by zero* error, is if the the second parameter in the Mod function (Count) was 0.  It should actually be a constant value of 4,  Make sure that you have `Option Explicit` as the first line in the module, to make sure that you're defining everything and that you don't have any easy typos.  (Make it default, by selecting Tools-->Options-->Require Variable Declaration)

Comment: thanks division by zero is gone but now the 1 to the left button come up with a error -1 for the following code.  if I start with black works till it gets to red then instead of going back to black it give error because its calculating -1 for the array index instead of 3 . Other left buttons 2 or 3 work but they get to red and don't start over from 3.       colors = Array("red", "blue", "brown", "black")
ColorIndex = posInArray(UserForm1.TextBox1.Text, colors)
Count = UBound(colors) + 1
Index = (ColorIndex + 2 - Count) Mod Count

UserForm1.TextBox1 = colors(Index)